# snapshots in firebase and swift

Tags: swift, firebase

I m trying to figure out how snapshots work in firebase and swift :

I have a list of posts and each one of them has properties (author, date and imageurl)
when I call a snapshot through   refpost.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in    ..

i can print the snapshot.value, which lists the database content.
How can I deconstruct the snapshot into an array so i will have something that I could pass to a tableview ?

something like value1 author date imageurl - value 2 author date imageurl etc..

or maybe multiple arrays for each property

sorry i m a noob :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```html
var ref = new Firebase("https://YOUR-URL.firebaseio.com/");
 ref.orderByChild("location").equalTo("United States").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
   document.write(snapshot.key());
    console.log(snapshot.key());
 });
```

Comment: great, and if I want the value number 7 of this snapshot ?

Comment: A basic Firebase query starts with one of our orderBy functions: `orderByChild()`, `orderByKey()`, or `orderByPriority()`. You can then combine these with five other methods to conduct complex queries: `limitToFirst()`, `limitToLast()`, `startAt()`, `endAt()`, and `equalTo()`. Figure out which function to use. See here: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-11-04-firebase-realtime-queries.html